# How to filter nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I use the filter() on nested items ? I am trying to retrieve all the data that has a projex.HeightPay === '1'. I would like to get back the Id, Name,System etc and the projex items if the HeightPay is 1.

For example:

```
  const fakeData = [
  {
    Id: "022173333101",
    Name: "Blue",
    System: "DESIGN",
    Squares: 0,
    Attributes: {
      projex: [
        {
          Project: "50",
          HeightPay: "1"
        },
        {
          Project: "50",
          HeightPay: "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    Customer: {
      Addr1: "Somewhere",
      Addr2: ""
    }
  }
];

// returns nothing
const found = fakeData.filter(data => data.Attributes.projex.HeightPay === "1");
```

Desired output:

```
  {
    Id: "022173333101",
    Name: "Blue",
    System: "DESIGN",
    Squares: 0,
    Attributes: {
      projex: [
        {
          Project: "50",
          HeightPay: "1"
        }
      ]
    },
    Customer: {
      Addr1: "Somewhere",
      Addr2: ""
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` to go through each element of the `fakeData` array and then filter on the child array `Attributes.projex` using `Array.prototype.filter` and return a new object from the `map` call for every iteration

The *new* object in the `Array.prototype.map` call is formed by taking *all* the properties of each element of `fakeData` using the object spread operator `...` except the `Attributes.projex` property and then assigning the new `Attributes.projex` array from the `Array.prototype.filter` to each new object:

```js
const fakeData = [ { Id: "022173333101", Name: "Blue", System: "DESIGN", Squares: 0, Attributes: { projex: [ { Project: "50", HeightPay: "1" }, { Project: "50", HeightPay: "0" } ] }, Customer: { Addr1: "Somewhere", Addr2: "" } } ];

const found = fakeData.map(data => ({
  ...data,
  Attributes: {
    projex: data.Attributes.projex.filter(({
      HeightPay
    }) => HeightPay === "1")
  }
}));
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const result = fakeData.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        Attributes: {
                projex: item.Attributes.projex.filter(e => e.HeightPay === "1")
        }
}))
```